# Trouble with void statements

Tags: c, void

My code for a simple trip program is below and I keep going around in circles on it.  I can get it down to one error where it says:

(The variable 'fuel' is being used without being initialized)...

I am stuck and looking for a hint/tip or help on what to do next.  If you have any questions on it please ask, and if there are any hints on making it a better post please let me know.

Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void WelcomeMessage();
void AskUserForInput();
void PrintTripSummary(float avgMiles, float minCost, float maxCost, float travelMiles, float fuel);

int main()
{
    WelcomeMessage();
    AskUserForInput();
    printf("\nThank you, please drive safely and have a nice trip!\n");
    return 0;
}

void WelcomeMessage()
{
    printf("Welcome to the Trip Planner!");
    printf("So you are ready to take a trip? Let me help you plan for\n");
    printf("your fuels costs and required stops to fill up your tank.\n");
    printf("============================================================\n");
    printf("Please provide answers to the prompts below and I will\n");
    printf("display a summary for you when I have computed the results.\n");
    printf("============================================================\n");
}

void AskUserForInput()
{
    float avgMiles, minCost, maxCost, travelMiles, fuel;
    do {
        printf("Input your car's average miles per gallon (enter 0 to quit) ");
        scanf("%f", &avgMiles);
        if (avgMiles == 0)
            break;
        printf("The lowest estimated price per gallon of fuel is: ");
        scanf("%f", &minCost);
        printf("The highest estimated price per gallon of fuel is: ");
        scanf("%f", &maxCost);
        printf("How many miles you plan to travel: ");
        scanf("%f", &travelMiles);
        PrintTripSummary(avgMiles, minCost, maxCost, travelMiles, fuel);
    } while (avgMiles != 0);
}

void PrintTripSummary(float avgMiles, float minCost, float maxCost, float travelMiles, float fuel)
{
    fuel = avgMiles/travelMiles;
    minCost = fuel*minCost;
    maxCost=fuel*maxCost;
    printf("== == == == == == == = Trip Summary == == == == == == == == == == \n\n");
    printf("You will need to purchase %.2f gallons of fuel.\n");
    printf("The approximate cost of fuel for your trip is between $%5.2f and $%5.2f \n",&minCost,&maxCost);
    printf("Thank you, please drive safely and have a nice trip!\n\n");
    printf("== == == == == == == = End Trip Summary == == == == == == == == ==\n\n");
}
```

Comment: avgMiles is a float. Do you expect it to be perfectly equal to zero? You should compare with some tolerance in your while loop.

Comment: `fuel` is uninitialized. Reading an uninitialized variable rsults in undefined behavior.

Comment: I think if the user inputs it, it's a lot safer to hope it's exactly 0.  More to the point, I think it's better to base your `break` on the output of `scanf` rather than basing it on being 0. You do no error checking in this process; it seems to me that you could at least check for negative values or none.

Answer (score 4):

You did not give local variable `fuel` a value in `AskUserForInput()`.

Answer (score 1):

What are your compiler settings that cause that to be an error and not a warning, BTW?  But yeah, you are using fuel uninitialized --

```
PrintTripSummary(avgMiles, minCost, maxCost, travelMiles, fuel);
```

I see that essentially this isn't important, because actually that function doesn't use fuel.  But the compiler doesn't see it, probably not when it is declared underneath it, and it definitely wouldn't be able to if it was in another compilation unit.  So, either take fuel out of the parameter list, or before you make that call, add

```
fuel = 0.0f;
```

Also, please note that you instead of:

```
void WelcomeMessage();
```

you really want:

```
void WelcomeMessage(void);
```

Due to backward compatibility reasons the first one in C does not declare the type of the arguments, and just won't warn no matter what are put in them.

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

1. `AskUserForInput()` does not read in value for fuel, thus it's uninitialized when it's passed to `PrintTripSummary()`
2. You probably don't need `fuel` parameter in `PrintTripSummary()` as you calculate it there instead. Just remove the parameter, declare fuel as local variable and calculate it there
3. You didn't put in `fuel` in `printf("You will need to purchase %.2f gallons of fuel.\n");`